# ISO 27001 structure and granularity of the content

Tags: corporate-policy, iso27001, iso27000

I'm new to ISO 27001 and my goal is to come up with an ISMS policy for an mid-size organisation. As I did not purchase the standards, I went to read up advisera's articles and went through their free foundation video course.

Now, I'm this confused state of trying to understand how to **structure the contents and the documents for ISMS**, and the **granularity of the content**.

I found 3 references online(link below) which I think it's pretty decent. However, the granularity of these documents are very different from one another.

1. https://www.gs.unsw.edu.au/policy/documents/itsecuritypolicy.pdf

   Separate into multiple documents. Section 2, high level description of control implemented from Annex A I believe. It then reference to very detail documents of how the control is enforced. Eg. https://www.gs.unsw.edu.au/policy/documents/ITSS_15.pdf 
   Do I need to provide this document(ITSS_15.pdf) with such granularity to get certified?
2. http://openaccess.uoc.edu/webapps/o2/bitstream/10609/59325/8/prodalTFM1216mem%C3%B2ria.pdf

   All in one document. Annex 1 talks about the annex A controls I believe, not as detailed as the detailed document referenced on section 2 of link 1.
3. http://www.easypqq.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/ISMS-Policy.pdf

   All in one document. I think that section 6 talks about annex A control, very high level

As you can see the 3 documents above, their granularity and structure of the contents are very different. How to structure the contents and the documents for ISMS, and the granularity of the content?

Comment: why not buy the documents?

Comment: @schroeder Because I see people offering ISO27001 templates all over the internet. It makes me think that purchasing the standard won't answer all my queries.

Comment: but your answers will come directly from the source documents

Answer (score 3):

Purchase the standard ISO 27001 & ISO 27002. If you want to certify to ISO 27001, you should at least have the standard so that you know what to do.
ISO 27002 5.1.1 answers your question on what the standards committee suggest you consider.

Regarding the first link, you do not need to provide this level of detail unless it is required by the standard. 
About the second link, an ISMS policy is not required in ISO 27001:2013. It was in ISO 27001:2005.
The third link reads like a summary of how they implemented ISO 27001:2013.

How to structure the contents and the documents for ISMS, and the granularity of the content - do so in a way that benefits your organisation and not just to certify to the standard.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering if i should purchase the standards or templates offered by 3rd party online. I was worried that purchasing the standard doesnt give me a systematic approach(like what should I do next and how do I do it).

Comment: How is an ISMS policy not required in ISO 27001:2013 ? Chapter 5.2 explicitly requires one.

Comment: An information security policy perhaps but not an ISMS policy

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted, a newer resource (circa 2019) became available: the Secure Controls Framework which contains a cross-reference to many major security standards, including ISO 2700x. (see https://www.securecontrolsframework.com ).

For ISO 27001/2, I hid the irrelevant standards columns and filtered anything that didn't apply to ISO 2700x. For each section of the ISO standards, the SCF has questions about your security practices, and how you can answer to achieve compliance (hint: it probably will make you change some of your procedures).

Comment: Hi Jeff, the cross-reference you mention would be very useful to me. But I can’t find it on the page on the SCF site. 

There’s a piece of text that suggests it (“Listed below are the thirty-two (32) domains that make up the SCF. There are approximately 750 controls that are categorized within these domains to make it easier to manage.”) but below that there’s only a small image with GDPR articles. 

Can you please indicate where you found the cross-reference? Thanks!

Comment: Already found it. The SCF site doesn't work as it should on an iPhone and doesn't display the top menu bar.